# How can I determine that the value of column1 in df1 contains in column1 in df2 starting strictly from the left (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'name': ['123456789', '5486544546', '65464564', '478615454']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'num': ['12345', '54865', '5464','7861']})
```

My question how modify the following function

```
df2['yes/no'] = df2['num'].apply(lambda x: df1['name'][df1['name'].astype(str).str.contains(str(x))].values[0] if len(df1['name'][df1['name'].astype(str).str.contains(str(x))].values)> 0 else 0)
```

the value of column1 in df1 contains in column1 in df2 starting strictly from the left
(that function works in any variations)

Desirable result:

| name | yes/no |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 123456789 |
| 54865 | 5486544546 |
| 5464 | 0 |
| 7861 | 0 |

Wrong result:

| num | yes/no |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 123456789 |
| 54865 | 5486544546 |
| 5464 | 65464564 |
| 7861 | 478615454 |

Comment: Could you provide us with the num and name columns in your example dataframes? Your function uses them but you forgot to provide them

Comment: can you explaine what is df2['num'] and df1['name']

Comment: can the value be available any row of df2 or only the same row as df1?

Comment: df2 should contain the value of df1 of any row

Answer (score 1):

if i get your point you need that :

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if str(df1['name'][i]).startswith(str(df2['num'][i])):
        l.append(df1['name'][i])
    else:l.append(0)
df2['yes/no']=l
```

out:

```
 num      yes/no
0  12345   123456789
1  54865  5486544546
2   5464           0
3   7861           0
```

Answer (score 1):

We combine (`concat`) two frames to get a temporary frame with two columns, which we then process line by line, checking if one text begins with another. If yes, return the value from the column, if not - 0

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['123456789', '5486544546', '65464564', '478615454']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'num': ['12345', '54865', '5464', '7861']})
df2['yes/no'] = pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.iat[1] if x.iat[1].startswith(x.iat[0]) else 0, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

```
     num      yes/no
0  12345   123456789
1  54865  5486544546
2   5464           0
3   7861           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to match in the starting you need to use startswith function.

**Code:**

```
#df1=pd.DataFrame({'name': ['123456789', '5486544546', '65464564', '478615454']})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'name': ['123456789', '5486544546', '65464564', '123456789']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'num': ['12345', '54865', '5464','7861']})
df2["yes/no"] = df2['num'].apply(lambda x: (df1['name'][df1['name'].astype(str).str.startswith(x)].to_list() or [0])[0])
```

**Explanation:**

```
df1['name'][df1['name'].astype(str).str.startswith(x)].to_list()
```

will create a list of value where df1 start with df2 value.

```
(df1['name'].astype(str).str.startswith(x)].to_list() or [0])[0]
```

if no values got we return a list with 0 i.e. [0] then retrieve the first element. Which will be the value if it matches or 0

**Output:**

```
0     123456789
1    5486544546
2             0
3             0
Name: yes/no, dtype: object
```

Comment: @АлексейР thanks for pointing it out. changed from to_value to to_list.